# How do I select a specific SSL certificate in FluentFTP?

Tags: ssl-certificate, sftp, filezilla, fluentftp

I'm connecting to a shared hosting site and the hosting company says it has a valid certificate, but I get a failure with FluentFTP. If I use Filezilla, I see a dropdown that lets me select "certificate in chain". Position 0 shows an expired certificate but position 1 shows a valid one.

How do I select the chain position in FluentFTP

My VB code for FluentFTP is

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications)
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
        Using conn = New FtpClient("secure11.host", "user", "pwd")
            conn.AutoConnect()
           'do something
        End Using
```

Comment: _"The Filzilla image shows the certificate expired at the same time it was created"_ - what are you talking about there, it shows that it was valid from 2023-03-28 to 2023-06-26 ...? And 2023-06-26 clearly is in the past, from today's perspective. Sounds to me as if your hoster simply isn't correct about the validity of their certificate.

Comment: The certificate is clear invalid. In FileZilla you accepted the invalid certificate. If that's acceptable solution for you, do the same in FluentFTP. This is not about *"selecting chain position"*.